# CakePHP find condition for a query between two dates

Tags: cakephp, date, time, between

I have a start and an end date in my database and a $date variable from a form field. I am now trying to query all the rows where $date is either = start/end date in the db, or ANY date between those two.

It's kind of the opposite of what is described in the docs of how daysAsSql works. I can't figure out how to get it to work. The following line does not work as a find condition in the controller:

```
'? BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($date, 'Item.date_start', 'Item.date_end'),
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. This is driving me crazy.

Here is the complete Query and corresponding SQL:

```
$conditions = array(
            'conditions' => array(
            'and' => array(
                '? BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($date, 'Item.date_start', 'Item.date_end'),
                'Item.title LIKE' => "%$title%",
                'Item.status_id =' => '1'
                )));

        $this->set('items', $this->Item->find('all', $conditions));



WHERE (('2012-10-06' BETWEEN 'Item.date_start' AND 'Item.date_end') AND (`Item`.`title` LIKE '%%') AND (`Item`.`status_id` = 1))
```

Comment: Kindly provide the complete query and the sql query equivalent cake is using to find the records.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329635/cakephp-model-with-between-dates

Comment: isnt this a complete duplicate of your previous http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899211/cakephp-search-between-2-date-records ???

Comment: Actually I tried to rephrase the question in a way that would make it simpler, as the first one didn't go anywhere. I realized that you could not delete questions that already have answers, when the second one got the right one. Sorry about the duplicate. I answered the first one according to the second one.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
$conditions = array(
        'conditions' => array(
        'and' => array(
                        array('Item.date_start <= ' => $date,
                              'Item.date_end >= ' => $date
                             ),
            'Item.title LIKE' => "%$title%",
            'Item.status_id =' => '1'
            )));
```

Try the above code and ask if it not worked for you.

**Edit:**
As per @Aryan request, if we have to find users registered between 1 month:

```
$start_date = '2013-05-26'; //should be in YYYY-MM-DD format
$this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.reg_date BETWEEN '.$start_date.' AND DATE_ADD('.$start_date.', INTERVAL 30 DAY)')));
```

Comment: And how I will do it if I have only one field(only start date not end date) in database and I have to find results between two days, for example find all user who registered from 26/5/2013 to 26/6/2013?

Comment: @Aryan, I added a solution for you. Please ask if you need more clarification. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here is `CakePHP BETWEEN` query example.

I'm defining my arrays as variables, and then using those variables in my CakePHP find function call:

```
// just return these two fields
$fields = array('uri', 'page_views');

// use this "between" range
$conditions = array('Event.date BETWEEN ? and ?' => array($start_date, $end_date));

// run the "select between" query
$results = $this->Event->find('all', 
         array('fields'=>$fields, 
               'conditions'=>$conditions));
```

[Ref from](http://alvinalexander.com/php/cakephp-find-between-select-query-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

General Example For CakePHP 2.x Query

```
        $_condition = array("TABLENAME.id" => $id, "TABLENAME.user_id" => array_unique($_array), 'date(TABLENAME.created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($start_date, $end_date));
        $result_array = $this->TABLENAME->find("all", array(
            'fields' => array("TABLENAME.id", "TABLENAME.user_id", 'TABLENAME.created_at'),
            "conditions" => $_condition,
            "group" => array("TABLENAME.id"), //fields to GROUP BY
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'alias' => 'T2',
                    'table' => 'TABLENAME2',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array('TABLENAME.t_id = TABLENAME2.t_id')
                ),
                array(
                    'alias' => 'T3',
                    'table' => 'TABLENAME3',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'IF(
                           TABLENAME.t3_id > 0,
                                T2.f_id = T3.f_id,
                                TABLENAME.ff_id = T2.ff_id
                            )'
                    )
                ),
            ),
            'recursive' => 0
                )
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more efficient and understandable `IN BETWEEN`  query in `cakephp 2.x`

```
$testing_log_device_site_name = $testingLogData['TestingLogDevice']['Siteid'];

$conditions = array('TestingLogDevice.dateee BETWEEN ? and ?' => array($start_date, $end_date));

$results = $this->TestingLogDevice->find('all', 
    array(
         'fields'=>array('dateee','timeee','Siteid'), 
         'conditions'=>array($conditions, 'TestingLogDevice.Siteid'=>$testing_log_device_site_name)
    )
);
pr($results);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$data=$this->post->find('all')->where([ 'id'=>$id,
'price between'=>$price1,'and'=>$price2])->toArray();
```

This query works as following:

```
select * from post where id=$id and price between $price1 and $price2;
```

> " --  'price between'=>$price1 --" become "price between $price1"

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
       $today = new DateTime( date('Y-m-d'));

       $fiveYearsBack = $today->sub(new DateInterval('P5Y'));
```

Comment: The already accepted answer was correct using "AND" clause of two snippets. What you just posted was not only wrong, but also put this back into current view without adding any valuable info.