# CakePHP between query with str_to_date mysql function

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Hi I am using table column datatype as varchar, and storing datetime values there.

I want to get the result from the table using between cakephp query.

normal between query I know when the column datatype is datetime, But In my case column datatype is Varchar. where I put str_to_date function in cakephp query. Please advice.

Normal query

```
select * from table where str_to_date(`value`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') between str_to_date('" . $search_string['value']['value1'] . "', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') and str_to_date('" . $search_string['value']['value2'] . "', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')";
```

I want above query with cakephp query.

cake normal between query - data type when datetime

```
 $this->Table->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Table.created ? between ?'=> array('2012-02-02','2012-03-03'))));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931633/cakephp-find-condition-for-a-query-between-two-dates/11932226#11932226

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try..

```
$this->Table->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Table.created BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array('2012-02-02','2012-03-03'))));
```

It may work for you as you missed AND operator over here..