# How to apply date filters in reports php

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How to apply date range filters to get rows of exact date

Below is my sql table

```
id  name     created
1   abc   2018-07-06 10:30:45 
2   test  2018-07-01 10:30:45  
3   raj   2018-07-05 10:30:45  
4   zyz   2018-07-08 10:30:45
```

But when i select date 2018/07/01 - 2018/07/01 it returns empty rows,

and when i select date 2018/07/01 - 2018/07/02 then it will shows below single row

```
2   test  2018-07-01 10:30:45
```

My query is, how to apply date filter if i need record of selected date in from and to date range filter

Below is my php code

```
public function clientReport(){
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $daterng = $this->request->data['daterange'];
            if(!empty($daterng)){
                $dates = explode("-", $daterng);
                $frmDate =  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dates[0]));
                $toDate =  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dates[1]));
            } 
            $conditions = [];
            if(!empty($frmDate)){
                $conditions['Orders.created >='] = $frmDate;
            }
            if(!empty($toDate)){
                $conditions['Orders.created <='] = $toDate;
            }
            $orders = $order
            ->find() 
            ->where($conditions);            
            $orders->enableHydration(false);  //  You can retrieve basic arrays by disabling hydration 
            if(!empty($orders)){
              $this->set('clientlist', $orders);
            }

        }        
    }
```

Comment: Can you show me the SQL query ?

Comment: yes plz..updating my query in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add time also in query

```
       if(!empty($frmDate)){
            $conditions['Orders.created >='] = $frmDate.' 00:00:00';
        }
        if(!empty($toDate)){
            $conditions['Orders.created <='] = $toDate.' 23:59:59';
        }
```

Comment: but i want to get all rows based on date only..if date matches then it will get then how to do so ??? bcoz i tried this also  $frmDate = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime($dates[0]));
                $toDate = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime($dates[1])); but not working

Comment: change `$toDate = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime($dates[1]))` to `$toDate = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59", strtotime($dates[1]))`

Comment: check my answer properly

Comment: But i am asking is how to implement it dynamically bcoz given mysql data is just an example..i have lots of rows in mt table and every rows have different times..so how to get based on date only..

Comment: It is dynamic. Only time is fix (start from beginning  of start day to end of last day)

Answer (score 1):

You need to "round up" the end date to 23:59:59 hours. You're actually working with timestamps, so a date will be converted to a date/time. 2018/07/01 probably becomes midnight 00:00:00 on that day. When searching from 2018/07/01 to 2018/07/01, what you actually want is to search from 2018/07/01 00:00:00 to 2018/07/01 23:59:59.

Comment: but i want to get all rows based on date only..if date matches then it will get then how to do so ??? bcoz i tried this also $frmDate = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime($dates[0])); $toDate = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime($dates[1])); but not working

Comment: it wont posible to get data based on date only..??

Answer (score 0):

To filter your data base on a date range you can use this

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE DATE(created) BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2018-07-01'
```

Comment: but how to use between in cakephp find

Comment: I think it would be something like this:
 ->where("DATE(created) BETWEEN ", $frmDate. " AND " . $toDate); 
Not 100% sure as I haven't worked with cakePHP
                              
This might be of some help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11932226/2911633